# Permutation/Combination - Officers and Age Restriction

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

I'm just confused. In a class, three students are randomly selected from a class of 20 students to be class president, vice president, and treasurer. What is the probability that they select the three oldest students?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please review [ask].  Note that in its present form (a problem statement without evidence of attempt to solve before posting or other *context*) the Question is likely to be placed on hold pending improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Probability that one of three oldest is selected for one of the positions is $P_1 = 3/20$.

Probability that one of the remaining two oldest is selected for the second position is $P_2 = 2/19$.

Probability that the last among the three oldest is selected for the final position is $P_3 = 1/18$.

The probability of all those events occuring is therefore $P_1*P_2*P_3 = 6/6840$

Alternatively, note that you can express the problem as choosing 3 people from 20 and there is one choice (the three oldest people) that represents success. So the answer is $\frac{1}{{20}\choose{3}} = \frac{3!(20-3)!}{20!} = 6/6840$

Comment: Your solution is clear, but you did not simplify the final fraction to lowest terms. Many people would refrain from doing homework assignments, but if you are willing to do them, why not take that last step?